# Allowing message dropping in websockets

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

Is there a simple method or library to allow a websocket to drop certain messages if bandwidth doesn't allow? Or any one of the following?

- to measure the queue size of outgoing messages that haven't yet reached a particular client
- to measure the approximate bitrate that a client has been receiving recent messages at
- to measure the time that a particular `write_message` finished being transmitted to the client

I'm using Tornado on the server side (`tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`) and vanilla JS on the client side. In my use case it's really only important that the server realize that a client is slow and throttle its messages (or use lossier compression) when it realizes that condition.

Comment: I don't think it is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this on top of what you have by having the client confirm every message it gets and then use that information on the server to adapt the sending of messages to each client.

This is the only way you will know which outgoing messages haven't yet reached the client, be able to approximate bitrate or figure out the time it took for the message to reach the client. You must consider that the message back to the server will also take time and that if you use timestamps on the client, they will likely not match your servers as clients have their time set incorrectly more often than not.